# How to build Javascript webrequest for google web search and parse google search results when HTML DOM is complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, google-search

I have a simple HTML page with a single search box and a search button. After the user hits Search button or hits enters, I need the javaScript to build the web Request query URL (with User Agent and/or cookie + query string) for Google and transfer the search to Google and return the search results (the response page) into a string or HTML document.

Then I want to parse the Google response JSON/string or HTML document and extract just the Title, links, Description, image and display them in a simple list on the same page. How can I do this parsing in run-time and displaying the parsed results on the same page?

I am using following code. I need help to build JavaScript web request for Google web search and to run parsing/debugging script when HTML DOM is complete.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Prototype Google Search Demo</title>

<script>
  var renderSearchElement = function() {
    google.search.cse.element.render(
      {
        div: "default",
        tag: 'search'
      });

  };
  var myCallback = function() {
    if (document.readyState == 'complete') {
      renderSearchElement();

    } else {
      google.setOnLoadCallback(renderSearchElement, true);

    }
  };

     window.__gcse = {
    parsetags: 'explicit',
    callback: myCallback
  };

  var loadElements = function() {
    var cx = '000888210889775888983:tmhkkjoq81m';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script'); gcse.type = 'text/javascript'; gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div>Prototype Google Search with one Text Box and Search Button using Javascript API</div>
<br/>

<form id="cref" action="http://www.google.com/cse">
  <!--<input type="hidden" name="cref" value="http://www.guha.com/cref_cse.xml" />-->
  <input type="text" name="q" size="40" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="'/cse'/brand'?form='cref" ></script>
<!-- Google CSE Search Box Ends -->
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="javascript:loadElements()">
  Click to start Google Search Prototype </button>

<div id="default"></div>

<!-- // I need help here to run parsing / debugging script after DOM is complete
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 function filterResultInserts(event) {
  console.log(event);
 // to show that DOM Node inserted event has been captured successfully
  alert("DOM Node Inserted"); 
// ....  parsing code here
}

var el = document.getElementByTagName('h3');
// target.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', filterResultInserts);
el.addEventListener('DOMNodeInserted', filterResultInserts);

});
</script>
-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should not do it that way. Use one of the APIs google provides instead: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: @CBroe if you look at the code you will notice that he is using Google's CSE API. Zack the problem is that you are trying to use two different approaches if you want to use the CSE API follow the guide here - https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element if you want to query results and handle the rendering yourself look at the api mentioned by CBroe. If you want to do the rendering yourself you might also want to use jQuery ajax calls - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Sorry, I was mislead by the description then … _“I need the javaScript to build the web Request query URL (with User Agent and/or cookie + query string)”_ – but I don’t see why one would have to do this manually when using a dedicated API, and especially why the user agent should have to be especially set …

Comment: Thanks CBroe and @Vishal. I need to build webRequest URL string like https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=testing+time using search keywords in input Box and initiate search request with all required headers and process the Google search result in response and then display parsed results on the same page. I have tried CSE API

Comment: @CBroe I believe that Zack has misinterpreted the API documentation. Zack if you use the CSE API Google already has the code to render your results you don't need to write your own code for it. If you want to render the results on your own you should use the RESTful API linked in CBrow's comment - you can make an ajax call and have the elements returned as a JSON object which you can then parse easily to show the results. You can try this out and update the question.